# How to make the 'Remember Me' function in Blazor Server login page work consistently in Android WebView?

Tags: java, c#, android, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server app where I use the build-in AuthenticationStateProvider service for Blazor Server. The login page of this service has a remember me function that works properly.

Within my Android App I show the Blazor Server website with a WebView

***MainActivity.Java:***

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        // Configure WebView settings
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);

        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
        CookieManager.getInstance().acceptThirdPartyCookies(webView);

        // Set WebView clients
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                progressBar.setProgress(progress);
            }
        });

        // Load the website
        webView.loadUrl("URL HERE");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // Handle back button press inside WebView
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

***Added to the AndroidManifest.xml:***
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

***Activity_main.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="0"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I login via the WebView app, the Remember Me function is working 1 out of 100 times and stores the credentials local on my phone within the app data. I know this because:

- I remain logged in when I clear my browser history on Google Chrome
- I remain logged in when I clear the cache storage of the app
- I am no longer logged in when I clear all data of the app (App info -> Storage -> Clear Data)

The other 99 out of 100 times it does not remember the login and when I open de WebView app again I have to login again.

How can I make this functionality work 100 out of 100 times? I never got to figure out when the app does save the login credentials and when it does not...

I activated JavaScript and (third party) coockies. Problem still not solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the WebView App is not always syncing the stored cookies correctly. To fix this add the following code to the MainActivity:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
       CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
    }
}
```

***full code:***

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        // Configure WebView settings
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);

        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
        CookieManager.getInstance().acceptThirdPartyCookies(webView);

        // Set WebView clients
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                progressBar.setProgress(progress);
            }
        });

        // Load the website
        webView.loadUrl("URL HERE");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // Handle back button press inside WebView
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```